# Consuming Soap Service in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap

I need to consume a soap service in spring boot. How can i do that easily using annotations like we do for Rest. I need to send headers, form the body for my service. Please help me with the solution

```
public String sendMessage(String processInstanceId) {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        String request = "<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:" + "SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" + "<SOAP:Body>"
                + "<SendMessage xmlns='http://schemas.cordys.com/bpm/execution/1.0'>" + "<receiver>" + processInstanceId
                + "</receiver>" + "<message overwrite='false' />" + "</SendMessage>" + "</SOAP:Body>"
                + "</SOAP:Envelope>";
        SendMessageAPI sendMessageObject = new SendMessageAPI();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(request));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        System.out.println("called service" + request);
        webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(
                "url",
                source, result);
        return "Success";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Spring Web Service](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) where it's present the `WebServiceTemplate` similar to the `RestTemplate`

In order to add SOAP Header and/or HTTP Header you can implement the `WebServiceMessageCallback` interface.

Here a simple example for adding HTTP Headers

The `WebServiceMessageCallback` implementation (note I'm using Axiom as MessageFactory)

```
public class WsHttpHeaderCallback implements WebServiceMessageCallback
{
    private String headerKey;
    private String headerValue;
    private String soapAction;

    public WsHttpHeaderCallback(String headerKey, String headerValue, String soapAction)
    {
        super();
        this.headerKey = headerKey;
        this.headerValue = headerValue;
        this.soapAction = soapAction;
    }

    public WsHttpHeaderCallback()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException
    {
        validateRequiredFields();
        addRequestHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(this.soapAction))
        {
            AxiomSoapMessage axiomMessage = (AxiomSoapMessage) message;
            axiomMessage.setSoapAction(this.soapAction);
        }       
    }
    private void addRequestHeader(String headerKey, String headerValue)
    {
        TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
        WebServiceConnection connection = context.getConnection();
        if (connection instanceof HttpComponentsConnection)
        {
            HttpComponentsConnection conn = (HttpComponentsConnection) connection;
            HttpPost post = conn.getHttpPost();
            post.addHeader(headerKey, headerValue); 
        }
        else if( connection instanceof ClientHttpRequestConnection )
        {
            ClientHttpRequestConnection conn = (ClientHttpRequestConnection)connection;
            conn.getClientHttpRequest().getHeaders().add(headerKey, headerValue);
        }
    }   
}
```

The `WebServiceMessageCallback` usage:

```
WebServiceResponse resp = (WebServiceResponse)webSvcTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(wsUrl, request, new WsHttpHeaderCallback(headerKey, headerValue, "http://ws.com/soapAction") );
```

I hope it's usefull

Angelo

Comment: Hi Angelo,  Thanks for your help on time. I got a good Knowledge on how to do. Now my another doubt is should i need a wsdl or any other additional requirements?

Comment: Well WSDL is the contract in SOAP architectures.. so sure you need WSDL if you are a client. If you are the server side, you can create the XSD for your SOAP messages and then you can leave to Spring WS the WSDL generation (but I prefer to start by creating the WSDL manually)

Comment: Hi Angelo, Thanks for the reply. It really helped me. I followed what was mentioned in [link](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/). Iam getting an error No marshaller registered. I have registered my marshaller and my wsdl class was created. Please let me know what is going wron

Comment: Sorry i followes as per this [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/)

Comment: May you post your spring configuration?

Comment: `public String sendMessage(String processInstanceId) {
  WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();

Comment: Please find my updated post. Iam getting "Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named "Envelope"

Comment: Your way is not the correct way to consume a SOAP message by using Spring-ws

Comment: ok. And thanks for your reply and help provided. And one more thing am just downloading <spring>(https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) project and imported in my Ide. For me wsdl class are not genrating in my project, but in genrated suources. Is that wrong. Please help me on that

Comment: Anyway you can give a look to this very simple and basic project https://github.com/angeloimm/spring-ws-sample